# confused with __STDCALL

Tags: c, dll, stdcall

i am trying to communicate with a dll from an exe and when i add WINAPI in the dll i get a NULL value during the call GetProcAddress().

Sample Code is:

EXE:

```
typedef int __declspec(dllexport) (WINAPI *fun)(int, int);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hdll;
    fun fp;

    int a = 120;
    int b = 80;

    hdll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("baladll.dll"));
    if (hdll != NULL)
    {
        fp = (fun)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hdll, "add");
        if (fp != NULL)
        {
            int c = fp(a, b);
            printf("\n Add is : %d", c);;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

DLL:

Header file:

```
int __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI add(int a, int b);
```

Source file:

```
#include "dll.h"

int  __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI add(int a, int b)
 {
     return a + b;
 }
```

When the same code is run without WINAPI call i get a non NULL value in GetProcAddress().

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You get a NULL when you pass the wrong argument to GetProcAddress().  Not a lot of choice when you have to guess which one could be wrong.  It is not "add".  Use the linker's .map file or use Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to see the real name.

Comment: Hi @Hans,

I did try using DUMPBIN /Exports and saw that dll name was same as that of what  I have mentioned in the exe.

what my question here was when i use 

typedef int __declspec(dllexport) (*fun)(int, int);

in my exe and the same declaration in my dll I do not see a NULL during the GetProcAddress call.

why i get a NULL on adding the "__stdcall " calling convention 
typedef int __declspec(dllexport) (WINAPI *fun)(int, int);


so any help on this would be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds unlikely, show us the output of Dumpbin.  The name should be "_add@8", the normal decoration for stdcall functions.

Comment: Hi @Hans Sorry about before.  I did Dumpbin.exe /exports on the dll which does not have WINAPI in the function. the output of which was like
 : 1 0 000110FA _add@8 = @ILT+245(_add@8) 
 Once I added WINAPI in the function I see the change, what you mentioned 
 1 0 000110FA _add@8 = @ILT+245(_add@8) 
 when I changed the code from fp = (fun)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hdll, "add"); 
                            to
 fp = (fun)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hdll, "_add@8");
 I got a non Null value and am able to communciate with both the app's.
 
 Thanks a lot!